# apply a Style on the selected button

Tags: c#, win-universal-app

I have a list of 10 Buttons,in which I want to apply a specific Style when I select that Button,I did like that:

```
private bool button1WasClicked = false;
private bool button2WasClicked = false;
private bool button3WasClicked = false;
.....
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    button1WasClicked = true;
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    button2WasClicked = true;
}



private void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
        if (button1WasClicked)
    { 
        apply the style on Button1
        button1WasClicked = false;
    }
       if (button2WasClicked)
    { 
        apply the style on Button2
        button2WasClicked = false;
    }
...... //complete the list of other buttons
        }
```

My question is,is there any other method I can use to apply the Style on the selected button of my 10 Buttons not the others

I hope someone can help me here..
thanks

Answer (score 1):

Theres is the [ToggleButton](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.primitives.togglebutton.aspx), which comes with a **Checked** property and has different **VisualStates** for Checked and Unchecked.